# Getting Runtime error 1004 after save functionality to my user form

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is used to habitate combo box with list of addresses in Sheets("Database").range("B:B") and "load" it into specific table, that we use to print offers. When I added save to the same line VBA it started giving me Run-time error **'1004': Method 'Range' of object _worksheet failed**. When I comment below code out, the UserForm loads with blank combobox.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim range As range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Database")
For Each range In ws.range("Full Property Address")
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem range.Value
Next range
End Sub
```

By the way the above stopped working when I added "save" functionality:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Address As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Form").Activate

Worksheets("Form").range("A3").Select

Address = Worksheets("Form").range("A3").Value

'--------------------------------
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Database").Select
range("B1").Select
Cells.Find(What:=Address, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
'--------------------------------followed by a whole bunch of those

Unload Me
Sheets("Form").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see the word `Save` anywhere in your code. I do see the word `.Select` though. You should take those out.

Comment: It might not be the issue, but you should not have your range object be named `range`. Variables sharing names with reserved words is a bad idea, so changing it to something like `theRange` or `rng` etc could solve your problem